# Generate txt file using Freemarker through running Maven task

Tags: maven, freemarker

My goal is to generate txt file using Freemarker (json + ftl template) by running
Maven task. I am able to generate file using Java, but I would like to create file e.g. at Maven generate-sources phase. Finally I would like to run script with Maven tasks, which would build package containing my txt file.

Is it possible to achieve? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I achive this by using freemarker-maven-plugin (https://github.com/fugerit79/freemarker-maven-plugin-bck).
I have add execution to my pom:

```
        <execution>
            <id>freemarker</id>
            <!-- Optional, defaults to generate-sources -->
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <!-- Required, must be generate -->
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Optional, defaults to src/main/freemarker -->
                <sourceDirectory>src/main/freemarker</sourceDirectory>
                <!-- Optional, defaults to src/main/freemarker/template -->
                <templateDirectory>src/main/freemarker/template</templateDirectory>
                <!-- Optional, defaults to src/main/freemarker/generator -->
                <generatorDirectory>src/main/freemarker/generator</generatorDirectory>
                <!-- Optional, defaults to target/generated-sources/freemarker -->
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/freemarker/configs/PRD/${mavenTest1}/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
```

And dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.fenvariel</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And I used this properties:

```
<properties>
    <mavenTest1>${mavenTest1}</mavenTest1>
</properties>
```

My project structure lookst like this:

```
/main/freemarker/generator  - json file
/main/freemarker/template  - ftl file
```

And file have generated when I call maven task 'compile' with parameter e.g.

```
-DmavenTest1=36
```